# How to sell digital and physical goods in one product in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a project in which I am required to offer a customer to download an ebook upon the purchase of a physical book. However, I've only found ways to sell physical and electronic products separately.

Is there a way to combine the 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you mean is to have a variable product ? You can have 2 variables, and one of them are virtual (your ebook).
Create a variable product and attribute him 1 variable, name it like you want (in this case the best is probably " Physical or Digital "), add the name of your both variables : ebook | book (or what you want).
After that, on the " variables " tab on the left from the same settings, add your both variables.
Like that, your variables are separate on the same product.
Check the box [virtual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTgzY.jpg) (see the picture), and for the second variable, you can not check the box.

I think it's what you want ? With that, the first variable with virtual option don't have any ship fees.

Comment: thank you very much, I was so lost with this :)